# How to display input data in testng report

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse

I have generate TestNG report in eclipse to display results of fail/pass testcases, but in report it does not display which input string I had passed into textbox. So I want to display input string in the report. How can I show this in report?

```
package com.sevenbits.diecast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.TestNGException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;

public class LoginPage
{

    static WebDriver driver;

    String  expectedurl = "http://example/account-page/";

    final String userblank1 = " ";
    final String passblank1 = " ";

    String  userblank2  = "gffjghj";
    String  passblank2  = "";


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()throws TestNGException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        driver.get("http://example.com");
        WebElement loginmain = driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-14235"));
        loginmain.click();
    }


    @Test

    public void blankdata(String uname,String password)
    {
        driver.get("http://example.com");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("log"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(userblank1);

        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name("pwd"));
        pass.clear();
        pass.sendKeys(passblank1);

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
        submit.click();

        String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedurl, actual);

    }

    @Test

    public void blankpassword(String uname,String password)
    {
        driver.get("http://example.com");
        //  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("log"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(userblank2);

        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name("pwd"));
        pass.clear();
        pass.sendKeys(passblank2);

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
        submit.click();

        String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedurl, actual);

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Data-provider` annotation we can pass parameter and display it into report

```
@DataProvider(name = "Authentication")

      public static Object[][] credentials() {

            return new Object[][] { { "name", "pass"}};

      }
```